# Arrays as buffer VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I need to create a FIFO buffer in VHDL. I need to use a 2 dimensional array to storage data like (number of data)(n-bit data).

If I create a single "big" array that storage for example 1000 entrys. Every new data clock I storage one slot. And every output data clock I output a data. What happen if this two clocks occour near at the same time?

For example:

```
if rising_edge(INPUT_DATA) then
                    Register_Array(Counter_IN) <= DataIN;
                    Counter_IN <= Counter_IN + 1;
end if;
if rising_edge(OUTPUT_DATA) then
                    DataOUT <= Register_Array(Counter_OUT);
                    Counter_OUT <= Counter_OUT + 1;
end if;
```

If it's possible to create a process like this, what happen if two clock are near at the same time?

Consider I can't lose any data.

Comment: Look at the answer i posted there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505213/image-processing-pipelining-in-vhdl/29508564#29508564

Comment: This is fine as long as you don't read and write at the same location nearly at the same time. Your fpga vendor should have timings information for collision, but your logic should really prevent that situation from happening. I think Xilinx guarantee the write in this situation, the read is not, however.

Comment: It the code that you have posted you shift your register. But I want to use a pointer and not to shift the register. Is that possible?

Comment: @ Drolet I've tryed but it doesn't synthesize. And if I use elsif rising_edge(OUTPUT_DATA) it run only write and not also output.

Comment: Is better to shift a single array or to create multiple arrays?

Comment: I just saw you trigger on rising_edges of `INPUT_DATA` and `OUTPUT_DATA`. These don't sound like a clock signal. Are they?

Comment: Yaro: No, it is not better to shift a array or create multiple arrays. Neither one will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking about here is a clock domain crossing FIFO, or CDC FIFO.
Clock domain crossing FIFOs are surprisingly difficult to design. There are many pitfalls, and most of them cannot be checked by simulation.

As for your arrays, you should use arrays of std_logic_vector, like in the answer linked to by @Nicolas Roudel.

But this is still far from a functioning CDC FIFO. You also need read and write pointers in gray format, gray to bin pointer conversion, clock domain crossings for the two gray pointers, empty and full indications, read and write signals, proper attributes to prevent the synthesizer from breaking the clock domain crossings, and timing constraints.
All this is needed to properly protect against exactly the thing you ask about: "What happens when two clocks occur at almost the same time?"

The thing that happens when two clocks occur at almost the same time is called "metastability", and it will cause all kinds of bad and unpredictable things in your design.

If you get only one thing in the design of the CDC FIFO wrong, your design will likely work fine in simulation, and even in hardware. Most of the time........ :-)

All FPGA vendors have ready-made CDC FIFOs which you can use. I would highly recommend that beginners consider using the ready-made FIFOs for production designs.
But at the same time, designing a CDC FIFOa is a nice challenge to learn about clock domain crossings and metastablity.

This is one of many pages where you can find information about how to handle clock domain crossings: https://filebox.ece.vt.edu/~athanas/4514/ledadoc/html/pol_cdc.html
There is also a related stackexchange answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97280/trying-to-understand-fifo-in-hardware-context

Comment: The question postulates a dual port memory with separate read and write pointers `Counter_IN` and `Counter_OUT`. The only occurrence of a clock crossing domain issue leading to potential metastability issues is when reading and writing to the same location concurrently.  Because FIFO handshaking signals (e.g. FULL, EMPTY, etc.) require clock domain crossing that can't happen. There's a delay measured in clocks before the affected handshaking signal gives permission to write to a no longer FULL FIFO or read from a no longer EMPTY FIFO. Your narrative is far from complete. Any references?

Comment: It is incomplete, because to completely explain all aspects of a CDC FIFO design would require a lengthy article.
I have added a reference for further reading.

Comment: Another paper on the subject is "Fourteen Ways to Fool Your Synchronizer", http://webee.technion.ac.il/~ran/papers/Sync_Errors_Feb03.pdf